# generate next available samaccountname in increments

Tags: powershell, count, numbers

I am trying to generate the next available ad account using incremental numbers. for example, my domain currently has accounts names"opr1000-opr1014", so when i run my script, i should expect opr1015, instead it gets stuck in a loop and never returns a value. I have it running a do while loop and increasing the numerical value in increments until it finds an unused value at which point the do while loop should no longer be true and the script should end. anyone have any ideas?

```
    $Account = "opr"
$Accountnum = "1000"
$Accountname = $account + $Accountnum
$Accountint = $account + $int
$int = [System.Decimal]::Parse($Accountnum)
do{
    $query = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$Accountname))"
    $result = ([adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()
    If($result){$int++}
}While($accountint)

"$account$Int"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite few mistakes, see this:

```
$Account = "opr"
$Accountnum = 1000
do
{
    $Accountname = $Account + $Accountnum;
    $query = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$Accountname))"
    $result = ([adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()
    if($result -eq $false) 
    {
      break
    }
    $Accountnum++
} while($true)
```

Comment: I tried your modified script and it still went through an endless loop, however when i switching the $Accountnum++ increment to the if instead of else then combining $Account$Accountnum as the output works!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Account = "opr"
$Accountnum = 1000
do
{
    $Accountname = $Account + $Accountnum;
    $query = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$Accountname))"
    $result = ([adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()
    if($result) 
    {
      $Accountnum++
    }else{

    break

}} while($true)



"$Account$Accountnum"
```